# How to replace \ followed by letters in java String?

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to delete all tokens that are started with \ and followed by any characters.
I created such a pattern:

```
input.replaceAll("\\[a-zA-Z0-9]*", "");
```

But it doesn't work because it doesn't delete `\rad` from string `5 4\rad`.

**EDIT**:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input="Wolf 3 3\4par";
        String replaceAll = input.replaceAll("\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9]*", "");
        System.out.println("replaceAll=" + replaceAll);
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\` is special *both* in string literals *and* in regular expressions. To put an actual `\` in a regular expression, you have to escape it *twice*. You also have to assign the result somewhere, which it wasn't clear from your question you were doing. So:

```
input = input.replaceAll("\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9]*", "");
```

Complete example: [Live Copy](http://ideone.com/Eeflml)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Temp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "4 5 \\rad";
        input = input.replaceAll("\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9]*", "");
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4 5
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I din't know it really.

Comment: Sorry, but my String is exactly `5 4\rad`. Indeed how to delete `\rad`?

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi sorry, but is your String in form `String input = "5 4\rad"` or you are reading your string from some source and in that source like file and in that source it is written as `5 4\rad`?

Comment: Such Strings are produced by BufferedReader that reads `.rtf` file.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi Tell me, when you print data from your file you see \ in output? If yes then string representing that output in Java will need to be escaped with another \ so it will have to be written as `"\\"`.

Comment: Indeed you are right. My string in actual program is `8\\par`. This regex works well!

Answer (score 2):

To create `\` literal in regex you need to pass `\\` to regex engine. But to create `\` literal in String you also have to escape it so you need to write it as `"\\"`.

- `\` literal in regex engine
- `\\` regex pattern
- `"\\\\"` String representing regex pattern

Now you are using one `\` in your regex pattern regex engine sees it as `\[` which escapes `[` making it simple literal.

Try this way

```
input.replaceAll("\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9]*", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

From

> Sorry, but my String is exactly 5 4\rad. Indeed how to delete \rad? – Volodymyr Levytskyi

Try

```
String k= "5 4\rad";
System.out.println(k.replaceAll("\r\\w*", ""));
```

*Output*

```
5 4
```

Comment: Thanks. There can be whatever after \. Because I am reading many lines of `.rtf` file. It might be `\2o3werd` or `\wed12`